# Eclipseプラグイン開発でポップアップメニューの名称が変わらない

Tags: eclipse

Eclipseプラグイン開発で、ポップアップメニューにメニューを追加しています。
メニュー自体は追加でき動作もするのですが、メニューの名称を変更してもその変更が反映されません。

メニューは次のコードで定義しています。

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
 <command defaultHandler="link.arata.mybatishelper.MyBatisHelperCommand"
 id="link.arata.mybatishelper.MyBatisHelperCommand" name="%XMLFileOpenAction.label">
 </command>
</extension>
```

名称自体はプロパティで定義しており、次のように記載しています

```
XMLFileOpenAction.label=対応するXMLファイルを開く
```

最初に定義した名称は正しく出るのですが、プロパティの値を変更しても最初に定義した名称のまま変わりません。
プログラムの他の部分を変更するとその部分はきちんと反映されます。
どうすると反映されるのでしょうか。

試したこと

- リテラルにしたりプロパティ値にしたりしていると、たまに変わることもあるのですが法則性はなさそうです
- プロジェクトのクリーン。変わらず

環境

- MaxOS 10.11.1
- Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers 4.5.1

Answer (score 1):

原因というか、Eclipseのバージョンをいろいろ変えて試してみたところ以下の事がわかりました。

メニューの名称が変更されないのは、
 - Eclipse 4.5
 - Eclipse 4.4
 - Eclipse 4.3

変更されるのは
 - Eclipse 4.2
 - Eclipse 3.7

でした。いちおうWindows版のEclipse 4.5も試してみましたが、メニューの名称は変わりませんでした。
しかたがないので、Eclipse 4.2で開発はしようと思います。